# Changing date format on [(ngModel)] using ngx-datepicker

Tags: angular, date, ngx-bootstrap

I have a web form that captures date of birth. I do this using `ngx-bootstrap` version: 2.0.2 datepicker module. 
I have an API that accepts date values only as `MM-dd-yyyy` format. My challenge is shape this date value so that I can send it to the API.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Using `bsConfig` as below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bsConfig = {
      containerClass: 'theme-red',
      dateInputFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy'
    };
}
```

And here is my html input:

```
<input class="form-control" 
        type="text" bsDatepicker 
        [bsConfig]="bsConfig" 
        placeholder="Date of Birth" 
        [(bsValue)]="participant.dob" value="{{ participant.dob | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}"
        name="dob" 
        [(ngModel)]="participant.dob" 
        #dob="ngModel">
```

When I select the date from the datepicker, I see the date as format that I set in ngOnInit. However, the actual date value is `{ "dob": "2018-06-07T16:53:52.000Z" }`. This is the date I'm sending to the API. Therefore, it doesn't work. As I mentioned above, the date format that I need to send to the API must be `MM-dd-yyyy` format.

How can I shape this captured date format so that I can send this value to my API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending your date to your API, transform it using [`formatDate()`](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate).

Don't forget to import it: `import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';`

```
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}
myDate;
bsConfig;

ngOnInit() {
  this.bsConfig = {
    containerClass: 'theme-red',
    dateInputFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy'
  };
}

sendDataToApi() {
  const date = formatDate(this.myDate, this.bsConfig.dateInputFormat, this.locale);
  howeverImSendingDataToApi(whateverData, date);
}
```